Issue with Generic params Method in C# - Method Not Recognizing Multiple IList Parameters
Problem:
I have a method that uses generics and params to accept multiple IList parameters. However, when calling this method with multiple ObservableCollection parameters, one of the calls is not working as expected.
Code
public class Test
{
    public ObservableCollection<ModelDetail> Details { get; set; } = new();
    public ObservableCollection<ModelCostCenterDetail> CostCenterDetails { get; set; } = new();
    public ObservableCollection<ModelVoucherAdjustmentDetail> VoucherAdjustments { get; set; } = new();

    public Test()
    {
        // it is not working 
        //Main Problem is in this line
        **Details.DeleteRows2(CostCenterDetails,VoucherAdjustments);**     

        // it is   working 
        Details.DeleteRows2(CostCenterDetails);

        // it is also  working 
        Details.DeleteRows2(VoucherAdjustments);
    }
}

public class BaseModelTransactionDetails { }
public class BaseModelTransactionSubDetails { }
public class ModelDetail : BaseModelTransactionDetails { }


public class ModelCostCenterDetail: BaseModelTransactionSubDetails { }

public class ModelVoucherAdjustmentDetail
    : BaseModelTransactionSubDetails { }

public static class Test2
{
    public static void DeleteRows2<T1, T2>(
        this IList<T1> detailsCollection,
        params IList<T2>[] subDetailsCollections)
    where T1 : BaseModelTransactionDetails
    where T2 : BaseModelTransactionSubDetails { }
}

Issue
When I call Details.DeleteRows2 with multiple ObservableCollection parameters, the method fails to compile with error: The type arguments for method 'Test2.DeleteRows2<T1, T2>(IList, params IList[])' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
The calls with a single parameter work fine, but the method call with multiple parameters does not.
Questions:

Why is the method call with multiple IList parameters not working?
Are there any issues with the generic constraints or params usage in this method?
How can I adjust the method or usage to resolve this issue?

Additional Information:

The method works fine with individual IList parameters.
The problem occurs only when multiple IList parameters are provided in a single method call.


Please provide the exact error message you get.

What is DeleteRows2? Where is the error?

What does DeleteRows2 do to the lists in subDetailsCollections? If it's only reading from them, I'd suggest changing the parameter type to IEnumerable<BaseModelTransactionSubDetails> and skip the generics but it's difficult to know for sure. You current problem is that the compiler has to pick one specific type for T2 in that call, and you're not giving it a possibility to do so.

You tell me. What should T2 be?

@Sweeper  it should BaseModelTransactionSubDetails

Well it can't be that. Neither ObservableCollection<ModelCostCenterDetail> nor ObservableCollection<ModelVoucherAdjustmentDetail> are convertible to that type. List<Child> is not List<Parent>.

@Sweeper baseclass of ModelVoucherAdjustmentDetail and ModelCostCenterDetail are BaseModelTransactionSubDetails so , it is.

ModelVoucherAdjustmentDetail is derived from BaseModelTransactionSubDetails, but IList<ModelVoucherAdjustmentDetail> is not derived from IList<BaseModelTransactionSubDetails>. Unless the type parameter is covariant, but IList<T> isn't.

@shingo but it is working when we pass single parameter

Becasue a single parameter can be inferred as IList<ModelCostCenterDetail> or IList<ModelVoucherAdjustmentDetail>.

Does this work?  Test2.DeleteRows2<ModelDetail,BaseModelTransactionSubDetails>         .DeleteRows2( Details, CostCenterDetails, VoucherAdjustments );

This seems to be but one more instance of the various iterations of covariance in generics question.

@MikeNakis , not working.

Uhh, I made a mistake, I meant Test2.DeleteRows2<ModelDetail,BaseModelTransactionSubDetails>( Details, CostCenterDetails, VoucherAdjustments ); I hope this is what you tried.

@MikeNakis, i have already tried but not working

If you repleace IList with IEnumerable it works (for me at least)

Ok I forgot to mention you need to mention the base type during the call.
Details.DeleteRows2<ModelDetail, BaseModelTransactionSubDetails>(...)
OR you do
params IEnumerable[] subDet
